# how to switch between Radio Button android

Tags: android, radio-button, android-alertdialog, radio-group

I have Three Radio Buttons .. Now When i want to switch between radio button I am using an Alert Dialog Box .. Now on Click of **YES** the other radio button is selected but on **NO** it not able to going to previous radio button ..

Here is my code :

```
RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton pre, during, post;
String lastChecked = "pre";   //This is the Flag which i m using 

radioGroup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            lastCheckedid = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        }
    });
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            lastCheckedid = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            if (pre.isChecked()) {
                lastChecked = "pre";
                getlastchecked();
            } else if (during.isChecked()) {
                lastChecked = "during";
                getlastchecked();
            } else if (post.isChecked()) {
                lastChecked = "post";
                getlastchecked();
            }
        }
    });
private void getlastchecked() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialog2.setTitle("Confirm Delete...");
        alertDialog2.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this post ?");
        alertDialog2.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);
        alertDialog2.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                imageView1.setImageDrawable(null);
                textview_imagename1.setText("");
                imageView2.setImageDrawable(null);
                textview_imagename2.setText("");
                imageView3.setImageDrawable(null);
                textview_imagename3.setText("");
            }
        });
        alertDialog2.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (lastCheckedid) {
                    case R.id.pre:
if (lastChecked.equals("during")){
during.setChecked(true);}
else if (lastCheck.equals("post")){
post.setChecked(true);}
                        break;
                    case R.id.during:
if (lastChecked.equals("pre")){
pre.setChecked(true);}
else if (lastCheck.equals("post")){
post.setChecked(true);}
                        break;
                    case R.id.post:
if (lastChecked.equals("during")){
during.setChecked(true);}
else if (lastCheck.equals("pre")){
pre.setChecked(true);}
                        break;
                }
    }
        });
        alertDialog2.show();
    }
```

the Condition of **NO** is Not Working... Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is difficult for getting previous value of checked button and get back check to that state. First, your coding has lastCheckedid which is not right as per use name. So, I have changed that to curCheckedid and try and implement solution of your problem in demo. I hope this will solve your problem. Try below code:-

In define varible

```
RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton pre, during, post;
String lastChecked = "pre";   //This is the Flag which i m using
int curCheckedid;
boolean isClickSet = true;
```

after that for initialize listeners :-

```
    lastChecked = "pre";
    curCheckedid = pre.getId();
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            curCheckedid = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            if (pre.isChecked()) {
                if(lastChecked != "pre" && isClickSet)
                    getlastchecked();
                else {
                    isClickSet = true;
                    lastChecked = "pre";
                }
            } else if (during.isChecked()&& isClickSet) {
                if(lastChecked != "during")
                    getlastchecked();
                else {
                    isClickSet = true;
                    lastChecked = "during";
                }
            } else if (post.isChecked()&& isClickSet) {
                if(lastChecked != "post")
                    getlastchecked();
                else {
                    isClickSet = true;
                    lastChecked = "post";
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

and separate getlastchecked() method:-

```
private void getlastchecked() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    alertDialog2.setTitle("Confirm Delete...");
    alertDialog2.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this post ?");
    alertDialog2.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);
    alertDialog2.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            imageView1.setImageDrawable(null);
            textview_imagename1.setText("");
            imageView2.setImageDrawable(null);
            textview_imagename2.setText("");
            imageView3.setImageDrawable(null);
            textview_imagename3.setText("");

            if (pre.isChecked())
                lastChecked = "pre";
            else if (during.isChecked())
                lastChecked = "during";
            else if (post.isChecked())
                lastChecked = "post";
            isClickSet = true;
        }
    });
    alertDialog2.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (curCheckedid) {
                case R.id.pre:
                    if (lastChecked.equals("during")){
                        isClickSet = false;
                        during.setChecked(true);
                        isClickSet = true;
                        lastChecked = "during";}
                    else if (lastChecked.equals("post")){
                        isClickSet = false;
                        post.setChecked(true);
                        isClickSet = true;
                        lastChecked = "post";}
                    break;
                case R.id.during:
                    if (lastChecked.equals("pre")){
                        isClickSet = false;
                        pre.setChecked(true);
                        isClickSet = true;
                        lastChecked = "pre";}
                    else if (lastChecked.equals("post")){
                        isClickSet = false;
                        post.setChecked(true);
                        isClickSet = true;
                        lastChecked = "post";}
                    break;
                case R.id.post:
                    if (lastChecked.equals("during")){
                        isClickSet = false;
                        during.setChecked(true);
                        isClickSet = true;
                        lastChecked = "during";}
                    else if (lastChecked.equals("pre")){
                        isClickSet = false;
                        pre.setChecked(true);
                        isClickSet = true;
                        lastChecked = "pre";}
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    alertDialog2.show();
}
```

Comment: sorry for late reply .this has solved my problem .. thank for your solution . appreciated your time .. @NitinPatel

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RadioGroup registerGender = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.regsiter_gender);
int selectedId = registerGender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
// find the radiobutton by returned id
radioButtonGender = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
radioButtonGender.getText().toString().trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line from OnCheckedCHangeListener

```
lastCheckedid = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

This line will save the newly checked value into lastCheckedId and then create the AlertDialog. Now,in switch, nothing will happen because lastCheckedId is having the current checked Id. Just remove that line and try again